# Cannot reproduce a GPO effect due to server version?

Tags: group-policy, background

I am running a domain with functional level Windows Server 2008 R2, within this environment I have host machines that run Windows Server 2012 R2.

This environment is running nothing custom everything is about as "out-of-the-box" as it can be.

I would like to enforce an image for the login screen (*note: NOT the lock screen) on these Server 2012 machines and cannot find a GPO setting to achieve this, there are options to enforce wallpapers and lockscreens but not for the login screen.

I am looking to avoid using 3rd-party software for this goal

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported on Windows Server 2012 (R2).  If you look at the group policy setting that allows custom logon background in 2008 (Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\  'Always use custom login background' ) , it specifically states that it is only supported on Win 7 and 2008 (R2).